# ReSharper, dotCover 2.2 + xUnit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, xunit, dotcover

I'm attempting to run dotCover on an xunit unit test. No matter which test I attempt to cover, they all give me the same result:

```
Inconclusive: Test wasn't run
```

So no matter what, dotCover doesn't find the coverage for any of my tests.

I am using ReSharper's unit test runner, and I am able to run the unit tests within VS inside the `Unit Test Sessions` window, so all of my unit tests run successfully.

When I attempt to cover a unit test (I've tried using the icon to the left of the test, the test all button in the `Unit Test Sessions` window, and right-clicking a unit test and saying `Cover Unit Tests` from within the same window), I always get the same message: `Inconclusive: Test wasn't run`.

My setup:

- Visual Studio 2010
- ReSharper 7.1
- dotCover 2.2
- xunit 1.9.1.1600

I've also set up both (http://xunitcontrib.codeplex.com/)

- xunitcontrib-resharper 0.7 (RS 7.1, 6.1.1)
- xunitcontrib-dotcover 0.7 (dotCover 2.0 - 2.2)

so that I should be able to use the xunit test runner from within VS.

Any help in getting the code coverage to work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am experiencing this same issue with VS2013, ReSharper 8.2, and DotCover 2.7. Any solution?

Comment: @Cirem Eeek, this was long ago! I don't remember what I did -- if anything -- to solve what I was working with at the time, but since then if I run into issues with xunit I've found the most common issue is forgetting to declare my unit test logic as public. Without declaring them as public xunit cannot find them, which could lead to this error.

Answer (score 0):

"Inconclusive Test" means that test execution was scheduled in task runner, but didn't get any response from it.
It can be a problem with xUnitContrib itself. Can I ask you for dotCover logs to check if dotCover was actually called from the UTR with xUnit plugin?